# Unexpected reference to variable in anonymous function

Tags: javascript

The following JavaScript has some unwanted behaviour:

```
<html>
<script>
  function AddEventListener(el, listener)
  {
    el.addEventListener ? el.addEventListener('click', listener) : 
                          el.attachEvent('onclick', listener);
  }

  function Init(parent) 
  {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerText = "Span1";

    AddEventListener(span, function() { alert(span.innerText); } ); 
    parent.appendChild(span);
    var span = document.createElement("span");

    span.innerText = "Span2";
    parent.appendChild(span);
  }
</script>
<body onload="Init(document.getElementById('drop'));">
  <div id='drop'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you click on `Span1`, `Span2` is shown in the alert window. I understand why: javascript variable scope. But I don't know how to solve it.

Some context: I used `this.innerHTML` which works fine except in IE8. `this` points to the window in IE8, not to the parent of the event listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a global variable in your click callback, you can use the `event` parameter that is being passed to every event you register, and then use its `event.target` parameter to get the DOM element that participated in the event.

For that, you may change your event listener registering to: `AddEventListener(span,function(event) {alert((event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement).innerText);});`

I've set up an example of it using your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/dvirazulay/fTa6T/1/

Comment: Yes, that's indeed a good one. A minor extension will make it work on IE8 too: `AddEventListener(span,function() {alert((event.target?event.target:event.srcElement).innerText);});`

Comment: This won't work in IE8, and in cases where there are nested elements, the `.target` could be one of those instead of the element to which the handler is bound.

Comment: @Tin: added in the answer to support IE8

Answer (score 2):

You can return a function instead of just declaring one, but I like @Dvir Azulay suggestion better:

```
function CreateAlert(span)
{
    return function() { alert(span.InnerText); };
}

function Init(parent) 
{
    var span=document.createElement("span");
    span.innerText="Span1";
    AddEventListener(span, CreateAlert(span)); 
    parent.appendChild(span);
    var span=document.createElement("span");
    span.innerText="Span2";
    parent.appendChild(span);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (changed the second definition of span to span2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>

function AddEventListener(el,listener)
{
  el.addEventListener ? el.addEventListener('click', listener) :     el.attachEvent('onclick', listener);
}

function Init(parent) 
{
 var span=document.createElement("span");
 span.innerText="Span1";
 AddEventListener(span,function() {alert(span.innerText);}); 
 parent.appendChild(span);
 var span2=document.createElement("span");
 span2.innerText="Span2";
 parent.appendChild(span2);
}
</script>
<body onload="Init(document.getElementById('drop'));">
<div id='drop'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know this will work but then I have to ensure all variables used have a unique name in the whole scope. In this simplified example it would be feasible...